# How can an object contained by another can mutate private data members of container object?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

Lets say we have an object elevator
Elevator have states for open and closed doors,
elevators door is a different object
ie,

```
Class Elevator{

private:
ElevatorDoor door;
int state
};
```

What I want to do is, when a person tries to open  elevator door, she has to interact with door object not elevator itself, but the door object should be able to mutate a private data member (which is state).
How is this possible?

Comment: That piece of state belongs to the door, not the elevator.

Comment: Pass a reference to `state` to `door`'s `Open` function (you do have one, right?). But yeah, I agree with Mat.

Answer (score 2):

First, move the `state` into ElevatorDoor class itself:

```
class ElevatorDoor
{
public:
  ElevatorDoor() { state = DoorClosed; }
  void Open() { state = DoorOpen; }
  void Close() { state = DoorClosed; }
  bool IsClosed() { return (state == DoorClosed); }
private:
  int state;
};
```

You can have a function that produces a reference to `ElevatorDoor`, or you can make `Person` a friend of `Elevator`, so that `Person` can get to the private members of `Elevator`.

E.g:

```
class Elevator{
public:
  ElevatorDoor& GetDoor() { return door; }

private:
  ElevatorDoor door;
};
```

or

```
class Elevator{
  friend Person;
private:
  ElevatorDoor door;
};
```

In the second case, the `Person` can of course touch anything inside the `Elevator`.

Another option, which gives much more finegrained control over what can be done, is to have door manipulator functions on the Elevator:

```
class Elevator{
public:
  void OpenDoor() { door->Open(); }
  void CloseDoor() { door->Close(); }
private:
  ElevatorDoor door;
};
```